# Can't fetch post likes with SQLAlchemy in Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

It's my intent to fetch `post.likes.count` in my blog application. But it doesn't work because of method error.

error:

```
'method object' has no attribute 'count'
```

here is my code:

**app/templates/post/show.html**

```py
<div class="like">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
  <p>{{ post.likes.count }}</p>
</div>
```

**app/models.py**

```py
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String)
    content = db.Column(db.Text)

    def likes(self):
        likes = db.session.query(PostLike).filter(PostLike.issue_id == self.id)
        return likes

class PostLike(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
    user = db.relationship("User", backref='user_post_like', foreign_keys=[user_id])
    post = db.relationship("Post", backref='post_user_like', foreign_keys=[post_id])

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<PostLike %r>'
```

Post likes result:

```py
(Pdb) post.likes
<bound method Post.likes of <Post 'xxxxxxxx'>
```

Comment: You have to **call** your method. `post.likes().count`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks right!

Answer (score 1):

from:

```py
<div class="like">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
  <p>{{ post.likes.count }}</p>
</div>
```

to:

```py
<div class="like">
  <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
  <p>{{ post.likes().count() }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to specify which template engine you're using - the above is correct for Jinja but wouldn't work in Django for example.